# Expected index of a random element in a list of expected length 1+\alpha

Tags: expected-value

I have a list $l$ with $E(|l|)=1+\alpha$, where $\alpha>0$.
I choose a random element uniformly from $l$ and want to know what is the expectation of the index of this element in the list.

If $\alpha$ is an integer this question is simple, as I need to calculate $(1+2+...(1+\alpha))/(1+\alpha)=(2+\alpha)/2$. Is there a simple reasoning for calculating the expectation in the case that alpha is not an integer?

Comment: You would get the same result.  It is an application of the law of total expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is exactly the same for non-integer $\alpha$.

If $L$ is the length of the list and $X$ is the index, then $X|L\sim\mathrm{Unif}[1,L]$ and we know that $\mathbb{E}(X|L)=(1+L)/2$.

Iterating expectations gives $\mathbb{E}(X)=(1+\mathbb{E}(L))/2=(\alpha+2)/2$, as in your solution.